# Change require to import-export

Tags: javascript, import, require

In my node project I use new features of import/export property and I add my package.json file "type": "module"
Now In this project I have to add socket.io but socket file comes to require property. I add the socket require script turns me a error. How can I fix the problem? Can I use fix this ( require and import)

const socketio = require('socket.io');
^

ReferenceError: require is not defined

I have this error on my terminal

Comment: have you ran the npm install?

Comment: Yes I do.const socketio = require('socket.io');
                 ^

ReferenceError: require is not defined

Comment: how are you running the file?